# Como dividir un integer entre el mes actual en mysql

Tags: mysql

Estoy creando una vista que me muestre ingreso y me lo divida entre el més actual.

He intentado varias formas que expongo, pero ninguna me ha funcionado:

```
select month(CURRENT_DATE) as mes, 
       round(sum(quantity),2) as 'Ingreso_Anual_Actual', 
       round('Ingreso_Anual_Actual'/ 'mes'),2) as 'Ingreso_Mensual_Neto' 
from recibos 
where operacion='ingreso' 
and YEAR(CURRENT_DATE);
```

```
select month(CURRENT_DATE) as mes, 
       round(sum(quantity),2) as 'Ingreso_Anual_Actual', 
       round(sum(quantity)/'mes'),2) as 'Ingreso_Mensual_Neto' 
from recibos 
where operacion='ingreso' 
and YEAR(CURRENT_DATE);
```

```
select round(sum(quantity),2) as 'Ingreso_Anual_Actual', 
       round(sum(quantity)/month(CURRENT_DATE)),2) as 'Ingreso_Mensual_Neto' 
from recibos 
where operacion='ingreso' 
and YEAR(CURRENT_DATE);
```

El error en los tres casos es:
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'round(sum(quantity),2) as 'Ingreso_Anual_Actual',
round('Ingreso_Anual_A' at line 1

Espero puedan ayudarme,
Saludos.

Comment: Hola, para usar condiciones debes separarlas por `AND` u `OR` de la forma (esto es un ejemplo)  `WHERE <condicion> AND <condicion> OR <condicion>`. Prueba corregir eso y agrega el mensaje de error que te devuelve la consulta o alguna información adicional para entender tu problema mejor

Comment: Aquello fue un lapsus lo lo tenía copiado en un notepad. el Error que sale es en los tres casos el mismo. ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'round(sum(quantity),2) as 'Ingreso_Anual_Actual', 
       round('Ingreso_Anual_A' at line 1

Comment: Lo que ocurre es que tienes paréntesis de más, debes colocarlo así: `round(sum(quantity)/month(CURRENT_DATE),2)`

Comment: Tenias razón gracias Josue.

Answer (score 0):

Solamente debes quitar un paréntesis que tienes de más en el round, seria algo asi:

```
select round(sum(quantity),2) as 'Ingreso_Anual_Actual', 
round(sum(quantity)/month(CURRENT_DATE),2) as 'Ingreso_Mensual_Neto' 
from recibos 
where operacion='ingreso' 
and YEAR(CURRENT_DATE);
```